# Refresh an instantiation of p5

Tags: p5.js

I have multiple instantiations of sketches in my document. How do I actually rerun specific instantiations with a screen refresh?

Assuming I have:

```javascript
function buildSketch(){

  var sketch1 = function(sketch){
    sketch.setup = function(){
      //Do my thing
    }
  }

  new p5(sketch1); 

}


function buildSecondSketch(){

  var sketch2 = function(sketch){
    sketch.setup = function(){
      //Do my thing
    }
  }

  new p5(sketch2); 

}
```

I know that if I attach the `sketch` to the window object, I can the refresh, but this seems... hacky e.g:

```javascript
 function buildSecondSketch(){

 window.sketch = sketch // Adding this seems to help

  var sketch2 = function(sketch){
    sketch.setup = function(){
      //Do my thing
    }
  }

  new p5(sketch2); 

}
```

And then I would just:

```javascript
sketch.setup()
```

Which works. But I have no idea why this works.

Comment: You really need to get into the habit of posting a [mcve] instead of disconnected snippets. Also, are you planning on accepting any of the answers to your previous questions?

Comment: Woah, my bad... I'm sorry, I thought I had accepted them.

Comment: Regarding the disconnected snippets, it is less about a piece of code actually working, and more about whether I'm understanding something principally or not. In the instance above(no pun intended) and [the last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311291/targeting-and-identifying-shapes-in-the-canvas), there is no 'issue' or bug that I'm getting... It's more about how to achieve the functionality that I'm after and I try to be as descriptive as possible when illustrating that. I hear your recommendation though, and will do better to adhere to the posted guidelines.

Comment: The [mcve] is as much for **us** as it is for you. Giving us some code that we can copy and paste (or a CodePen or JSFiddle) to play with makes it much easier to answer your question. Otherwise we have to create our own example program and guess at exactly what you're trying to do, which makes our job much harder Anything that makes it easier for us makes it more likely you'll get an answer. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** call the `setup()` function yourself.

The simplest thing to do might be to add a `refresh()` function to each of your sketches. This function would sipmly reset the state of your sketch by setting any sketch-level variables back to their original values. Then just call that function. This is basically what you're doing by calling `setup()` yourself, but avoids you short-circuiting P5.js's internal automatic function calling.

Either way, you have to keep around a reference to the sketch variables. You could do that using `window.sketch`, which is just creating a global variable, or you could declare them outside your `buildSketch()` functions.

You could also get rid of the old `p5` instances and reinstantiate them, but that would require keeping around a reference to each `p5` instance.

Comment: I ended up just attaching the instance to a global variable, and running it from that. Thanks!